# ExtJS 5 toolbar buttons don't align right when RTL is true

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5

Previsouly on my ExtJS 4 app when I created a toolbar and set rtl to true , the toolbar buttons aligned to the right (the hand icon is the first one)

[image]

Now I've tried doing the same with ExtJS 5 but what happens is that the order of the icons stays LTR althought its defined as RTL :

[image]

This is the code I used to define the panel :

```
Ext.define('GIS.view.Map', {
extend: 'GeoExt.MapPanel',
region: 'center',
xtype: 'map',
title: 'map',
rtl: true,
controller: 'mapcontroller',
map: map,
stateful: false,
border: true,
tbar: [
    {
        xtype: 'buttongroup',
        title: 'ניווט',
        enableOverflow: true,
        defaults: {
            scale: 'large',
            hideText: true
        },
        items: [
            {
                iconCls: 'pan48',
                handler: 'onPan'
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'zoomin48',                    
                handler: 'onZoomIn'
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'zoomout48',                    
                handler: 'onZoomOut'
            }
        ]
    }
],
initComponent: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

Any idea why the inner order of the icons don't change ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by manually adding to the css :

```
.x-rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}
```